# Joomla Component Develpment: JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file

Tags: joomla

I developed a joomla component. But I got this error while trying to install it.
"JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file"

Error
Path does not have a valid package.

Below is myforms.xml file

```
     <? xml version = "1.0"encoding = "utf-8" ?>
    <extension type="component" version="3.2" method="upgrade">
     <name>My Forms!</name>
    <creationDate>Sept 09 2014</creationDate>
    <author>Toni Ezeamaka</author>
    <authorEmail>tons613@ymail.com</authorEmail>
    <copyright>A-One GlobalSoft Technologies</copyright>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <description>A component for adding forms to my sites</description>

    <installfile>install.php</installfile>
    <uninstallfile>uninstall.php</uninstallfile>
    <scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>

    <update>
            <schemas>
                    <schemapath type="mysql">sql/updates/mysql/</schemapath>
            </schemas>
    </update>

    <files folder="site">
            <filename>index.html</filename>
            <filename>myforms.php</filename>
            <filename>controller/myforms.php</filename>
            <folder>views</folder>
            <folder>models</folder>
    </files>

    <administration>
            <!-- Administration Menu Section -->
            <menu>My Forms!</menu>
            <files folder="admin">
                    <filename>index.html</filename>
                    <filename>myforms.php</filename>
                    <filename>controller.php</filename>
                    <folder>sql</folder>
                    <folder>tables</folder>
                    <folder>models</folder>
                    <folder>views</folder>
            </files>
    </administration>
    </extension>
```

can someone help please?

Comment: It looks space in `<? xml` is the issue.

Comment: Oh Yes, that was the problem. It worked perfectly. Thanks @Irfan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue was with the space in `<? xml`

I changed it to    `<?xml version = "1.0"encoding = "utf-8"?>`

and it worked. Thanks to @Irfan